# Equivalent of C++ std::set in Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab

How can I define a `set` in Matlab which has these properties:

- Unique items
- Efficient search
- Ordered

Maybe there isn't a built-in container, So how can I combine some stuff to gain above things as same as `std::set` in C++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Java's HashSet like this:

```
>> x = java.util.HashSet;
>> x.add(1);
>> x.add(2);
>> x.contains(1)
ans = 
     1
>> x.contains(3)
ans = 
     0
>> x
x = 
[2.0, 1.0]
```

In the comments it was pointed out that a HashSet isn't ordered. Which is totally true. My mistake! You could use a TreeSet instead, which *is* ordered:

```
>> x = java.util.TreeSet;
>> x.add(1);
>> x.add(3);
>> x.add(2);
>> x
x = 
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Comment: Presumably a hash set isn't ordered?

Comment: @juanchopanza true, fixed.

Comment: aren't we looking for matlab solution?

Comment: @user40780 This is a MATLAB solution (the `>>` above is the MATLAB prompt)